# why x11docker can't call dbus

Tags: docker, centos7

When I use x11docker on centos7 as root,it always happen that 'Failed to get D-Bus connection'.

```
x11docker --desktop x11docker/xfce
x11docker --verbose --share /run/dbus/system_bus_socket --desktop  x11docker/xfce
```

Both were failed.